# Can someone explain the purpose of the highlighted part in the circuit?

Tags: power-supply, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply

[image: SMPS]

What is the purpose of the highlighted part in this circuit, and how does it affect the overall functionality of the circuit?

Could it be that the highlighted section of the circuit is used to supply power to the InnoSwitch IC? Would it also be possible to employ it to power other components?

Comment: It's a rectification diode and smoothing capacitor for the second primary winding to provide power to the controller IC once the power supply has started up. Startup itself is performed by an internal regulator in the controller charging up C4 from the Drain until there's enough energy in the capacitor for initial startup.

Comment: @Unimportant please post as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diode is in a slightly confusing position, but there's no functional difference between these two circuits:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feCggm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The transformer coil and diode can appear in any order, in the same way two series resistances can be swapped without changing net behaviour.

R1 and R2 are small loads to demonstrate behaviour. Both those circuits above are half-wave rectifiers, producing the same potential at A and B:

[image]
[image]

It might be possible to power other elements from this source, as long as you don't draw so much current as to affect the rectified signal. I wouldn't recommend it. One consequence would be bigger "dips" in the rectified and smoothed output (which could probably be fixed by increasing C1), but I don't know what U1 is expecting at pin BPP. Are these dips required as part of the design here? If so then you probably shouldn't mess with them.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation !

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is going to rectify the energy from that particular coil, and it feeds the *mains side* of the controller.

In theory you could use that to power other things, but (A) there's a lot of "if's" in whether it would work or not, and (B) that's on the mains side of the circuit -- there's not many useful things you could do with power on that side of the isolation barrier.

Comment: Appreciate the help!